# How to configure filter using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to add a Filter that need parameters given as FilterConfig. I'm adding it in WebApplicationInitializer::onStartup(ServletContext container) methods and it is well configured (the init method is called with correct FilterConfig).

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(container);

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic urlRewriteFilter = container.addFilter("UrlRewriteFilter", UrlRewriteFilter.class);
    urlRewriteFilter.addMappingForServletNames(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD), false, "/*");
    urlRewriteFilter.setInitParameter("confPath", "WEB-INF/urlrewrite-prod.xml");
}
```

The point is that I'm using Spring Security WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and my filter is never called (not present in filter chain).
If I add it with addFilterAfter there is no way to give him a FilterConfig.

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
  .exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(spnegoEntryPoint())
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .httpBasic()
        .and()
    .logout()
        .and()
    .addFilterBefore(spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authenticationManagerBean()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
    .addFilterAfter(new CacheFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
    .addFilterAfter(new UrlRewriteFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
 }
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in Filter mapping. I was calling addMappingForServletNames instead of addMappingForUrlPatterns

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(container);

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic urlRewriteFilter = container.addFilter("UrlRewriteFilter", UrlRewriteFilter.class);
    //urlRewriteFilter.addMappingForServletNames(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD), false, "/*");
    urlRewriteFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD), false, "/*");
    urlRewriteFilter.setInitParameter("confPath", "WEB-INF/urlrewrite-prod.xml");
}
```